# Why does some images not display in different browsers?

Tags: image, cross-browser

I've *unreal problem*.
I have a site, where are displaying images over an classical `<img>` tag.

All images are loading from the database, where is *URL column* of the image.
My problem is that **three of ten** images **are not display**.

But if I open the source code and click at the URL of the image, I can see image.

In source code is some looks like (just for a simple example):

```
<img src = "http://some.image/1.jpg" alt = "description" height = "140" width = "187" />
```

But the **biggest snag** is that **Opera displays all images correct**, but just in **FF**, **IE**, **Chrome** are mentioned problems.

I can not provide a *screenshots*, because the pages are a bit perverse. How can I show the site where the problem is? Or some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Is the HTML source (with surrounding tags) perverse as well?

Comment: Can you prepare a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (with non-perverse images) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: All images are bit perverse and from different site.

Comment: Perhaps the server is highly loaded so some images get a refused connection?

Comment: You can still prepare a fresh set of images (just some text or a gradient) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: What does the debugging console (chrome: CTRL+SHIFT+I > network > CTRL+F5) say?

Comment: Nice idea with Console. It writes me: GET 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: But why does Opera works with that issue?

Comment: You can look at the HTTP headers and URL sent by opera / other browsers.